# 487 Request Cancelled after invite request

Tags: java, sip

i'm actually developping an application that generates sip requests. when i send invite request i got a 487 request cancelled answer from server and the reason header is `Reason: X.int;reasoncode=0x00000835;add-info=05CC.0008.0001,Q.850;cause=127`
PS: i sent the same invite to the other interface of the server and it works well.
Have anyone idea about the reason of this answer? thnx in advance

Comment: From what I've google, Q.850 (the ITU-T recommendation that describes the SS7 cause codes) cause=127 is just *"Interworking, Unspecified"*. More information might be gathered from *reasoncode* and *add-info* parameters, but you might need to describe more of your set-up. My guess is that for some reason, your SIP request is attempted to be relayed over an ISDN/ISUP trunk and something fails.

Comment: Yeah i guess that too, but in fact i didn't find any information about the meaning of reasoncode and add-info! in the RFC there is no description about what does this means...

Comment: Perhaps you should indicate more details about your set-up. What you are talking to? what it is connected to? Perhaps show the INVITE you are sending that doesn't work and the INVITE that does work?

Comment: The problem was on the equipment itself which was the border controller... Thank you very much for your responses :)